# Ruby on Rails:{Form does not load template to registration#create when button submit is hit}

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

#This is the RegistrationCOntroller to link the Model to the Form so that the data can be placed and when it is submitted a message of thanks will appear
`

```
class RegistrationController < ApplicationController
    
    def new
        @user =  User.new
    end

    def create 
        render plain: "Thanks"
    end

end
```

`#The Form Page`

```
<div class = "d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <h1> Registration </h1>
</div>

<%= form_with module: @user, url: sign_up_path do |form| %>

    <div class = "mb-3">
        <%= form.label :email%>
        <%= form.text_field :email, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Exaple@gmail.com"%>
    </div>
    <div class = "mb-3">
        <%= form.label :password%>
        <%= form.password_field :password, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Password"%>
    </div>
    <div class = "mb-3">
        <%= form.label :password_confirmation%>
        <%= form.password_field :password_confirmation, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Password"%>
    </div>
    <div class = "mb-3">
        <%= form.submit "Register", class:"btn btn-primary"%>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

`#The routes for the project and the post method for the registration`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "articles#index"

  root to: "main#index"
  get "about", to: "about#index"

  get "sign_up", to: "registration#new"
  post "sign_up", to: "registration#create"
  
end
```

`
#Note when the button is hit or the form is submitted no new page appears, and when i check the terminal for a response

```
Started POST "/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-11-13 08:49:52 -0400
Processing by RegistrationController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"test@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Register"}
  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 10)
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 3.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 963)
```

#Also if i remove the PlainText thanks from the Registration Create section i end up with this instead

```
Started POST "/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-11-13 08:53:52 -0400
Processing by RegistrationController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"test@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Register"}
No template found for RegistrationController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 986)
```

#neither allows me to display my message on the post path "sign_up_path"

I tried renaming the routes path and trying various messages to display on the #create class object however I end up with the same result

Comment: I think you meant to write `form_with model: @user`. Not `module:`. I also don't get why this is tagged ruby-on-rails-4 when this code obviously is not for Rails 4.

Comment: Looks like you need to add a little more to your `create` action. Specifically you need to create a new instance, add the data from the form (passed by params) and then you need to save it. Then you need to redirect to whatever page you want to be displayed. And also what @max said.

Comment: @max I did the changes but the same issues occur.

Comment: Yeah that was just one of many problems with this code. Maybe try the quickstart guide? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: Start by stating the problem, then give the code